# Disable shopping when an item from a specific product category is in cart in Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, cart, custom-taxonomy

I am trying to Disable shopping if a an item from a specific product category is in cart (which is a subscription in form of product with tabs - checkout and shipping are stripped off). When that product is added to cart, no other products should be allowed to be add up.

I have tried those threads code:

- [Disable Woocommerce add to cart button if the product is already in cart](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49923032/3730754)
- [Prevent checkout for cart with specific category](https://gist.github.com/bekarice/99d479e6c91880b3b80a21a0b3415b7f)

But didn't helped.

How can I disable shopping if a specific product category is in cart on Woocommerce?

[image: output problem image]

Comment: That is the text of your initial question: **Disable shopping if specific category in cart woocommerce** *"i am trying to Disable shopping if a category is in the cart which is a subscription in form of product with tabs,checkout shipping stripped off.Once that category hidden which skips to checkout page is added to cart no other products should be allowed to add up.i took few references but didnt helped."*

Comment: yes i am looking for the same which is unresolved by solution given.thanks.Image attached shows shopping not disabled.

Comment: When you ask something you just need to be clear. If you ask for chicken, you will not get beef even if both are meat…

Comment: My answer is answering your initial question. So you should better make a new question, taking care with what you are asking, paying attention to the words and sentences to make it clear and understandable.

Comment: "When that product is added to cart, no other products should be allowed to be add up. " is mentioned above regards

Comment: When the product from your category is in cart (the subscription), no products can be added to cart (any add to cart action is disabled and return an error message) so this code works (just as explained in my answer). I hope than someone else will give you a more convenient answer.

Comment: with all due respect sir ......add to cart is not disabled ok wait for few minutes.thanks

Comment: With all respect… add to cart is not allowed once the subscription is in cart. **So in your web site something is making trouble.**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> **October 2018 - Improved updated code version:** 
> [Disable other product categories for a cart item from specific category in Woocommerce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52598329/disable-other-product-categories-for-a-cart-item-from-specific-category-in-wooco/52601311#52601311)

Try the following code, that will:

1. Avoid add to cart when a product from a specific product category is in cart
2. Remove other cart items when a product from a specific product category is added to cart

The code:

```
// Remove other items when our specific product is added to cart
add_action( 'woocommerce_add_to_cart', 'remove_other_products_on_add_to_cart', 10, 6 );
function remove_other_products_on_add_to_cart ( $cart_item_key, $product_id, $quantity, $variation_id, $variation, $cart_item_data ){
    // HERE set your product category (can be term IDs, slugs or names)
    $category = 'posters';

    // We remove other items when our specific product is added to cart
    if( has_term( $category, 'product_cat', $product_id ) ) {
        foreach( WC()->cart->get_cart() as $item_key => $cart_item ){
            if( ! has_term( $category, 'product_cat', $cart_item['product_id'] ) ) {
                WC()->cart->remove_cart_item( $item_key );
            }
        }
    }
}

// Avoid other items to be added to cart when our specific product is in cart
add_filter( 'woocommerce_add_to_cart_validation', 'check_and_limit_cart_items', 10, 3 );
function check_and_limit_cart_items ( $passed, $product_id, $quantity ){
    // HERE set your product category (can be term IDs, slugs or names)
    $category = 'posters';

    // We exit if the cart is empty
    if( WC()->cart->is_empty() )
        return $passed;

    // CHECK CART ITEMS: search for items from product category
    foreach ( WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item ){
        if( has_term( $category, 'product_cat', $cart_item['product_id'] ) ) {
            // Display an warning message
            wc_add_notice( __('A subscription is already in cart (Other items are not allowed in cart).', 'woocommerce' ), 'error' );
            // Avoid add to cart
            return false;
        }
    }
    return $passed;
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.

Comment: yes checked customization and disabled all plugins then too same error...ok i will come later will check one more time....

Comment: @AmitSharma Sorry, there was a typo error on the first function name… I have updated the code. It should work now.

Comment: @AmitSharma Tested again and it works just fine… You should try to clarify your explanations as they are not understandable. I can't do anything more for the moment.

Comment: problem is once subscription is in cart others product should not display. and should get deleted with a notice // Remove/disallow  other items when our specific product is in the cart... // We remove other items when our specific product is added to cart// Avoid other items to be added to cart when our specific product is in cart checked both but still prob exist

Comment: @AmitSharma You didn't ask that in your question… Actually when a subscription is added, it remove all other products from cart and avoid any other add to cart action: **so shopping is disabled**. Now to hide shop and product pages, that is another thing that you didn't ask in your initial question. **This answer works related to what you asked in your initial question.** If you want to hide shop and products, that is something different and you should ask a new question.

Comment: @AmitSharma I will not change my answer. and you shouldn't change the question. **You should ask a new question** and accept this answer as it works on your initial question.

Comment: Thanks that works but conflicts with multivendor plugin.
Btw I would like to learn or follow how do you visualize woocommerce structure.Regards

Comment: Hi, this code works perfectly fine for me, but I want it to redirect(sroll) to the notice on the products page, but unable to do so, kindly help me if possible