# Disable other product categories for a cart item from specific category in Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product, custom-taxonomy

I'm developing a webshop, with different aspects, the first is a regular shop, and the second is a night beer service. i've searched but can't find what i am looking for;

First the night beer service is a specific category that shouldn't be ordered with the regular items (if category `'beerservice'` is in the cart, disable all other categories to be added to the cart).

This option also needs to work vice-versa (the other wat around), so if a regular item is added to the cart, the category of `'beerservice'` should be disabled to add to the cart.

I am using this answer code that I have found: 
[Disable shopping when an item from a specific product category is in cart in Woocommerce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51938763/disable-shopping-when-an-item-from-a-specific-product-category-is-in-cart-in-woo/51941925#51941925)

That does the job partially, but it's only impossible to add multiple products from the same category, and is doesn't work vice-vera. I have replaced in this code

I also would like to add a time specific message like, 'Order ordered past TIME won't be delivered'(didn't research this) but if it isn't to much trouble.

Comment: Please, when you are using the code from an existing answer, **add always the link** in your question. If your are no making real changes to the code don't add the code in your question, just keep the link. Also note that in StackOverFlow, you can't ask multiple questions at once, as your question will be closed as too broad.

Comment: sorry! will keep it in mind, thanks for the heads-up

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code will check for parent product categories, so for a defined product category, it will:

- Avoid adding to cart other product categories when the defined category is in cart.
- It will remove cart items from other product categories when a product from the defined category is added to cart.

Improved code:

```
// Custom conditional function that checks for parent product categories
function has_parent_term( $product_id ) {
    // HERE set your targeted product category SLUG
    $category_slug = 'beerservice'; //  <====  <====  <====  <====  <====  <====  <====

    // Convert category term slug to term id
    $category_id   = get_term_by('slug', $category_slug, 'product_cat')->term_id;
    $parent_term_ids = array(); // Initializing

    // Loop through the current product category terms to get only parent main category term
    foreach( get_the_terms( $product_id, 'product_cat' ) as $term ){
        if( $term->parent > 0 ){
            $parent_term_ids[] = $term->parent; // Set the parent product category
        } else {
            $parent_term_ids[] = $term->term_id;
        }
    }
    return in_array( $category_id, $parent_term_ids );
}

// Avoid add to cart others product categories when "beerservice" is in cart
add_filter( 'woocommerce_add_to_cart_validation', 'specific_category_avoid_add_to_cart_others', 20, 3 );
function specific_category_avoid_add_to_cart_others( $passed, $product_id, $quantity) {
    if( WC()->cart->is_empty() || has_parent_term( $product_id ) ) {
        return $passed;
    }

    foreach( WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item ){
        if( has_parent_term( $cart_item['product_id'] ) ) {
            wc_add_notice( __('Alert message 1 (avoid add to cart)', 'woocommerce' ), 'error' ); // Display a custom error notice
            return false; // Avoid add to cart
        }
    }
    return $passed;
}

// Remove other items when our specific product is added to cart
add_action( 'woocommerce_add_to_cart', 'conditionally_remove_other_products', 20, 4 );
function conditionally_remove_other_products ( $cart_item_key, $product_id, $quantity, $variation_id ){
    if( has_parent_term( $product_id ) ) {
        foreach( WC()->cart->get_cart() as $item_key => $cart_item ){
            if( ! has_parent_term( $cart_item['product_id'] ) ) {
                WC()->cart->remove_cart_item( $item_key );
                wc_add_notice( __('Alert message 2 (Item removed from cart)', 'woocommerce' ), 'error' ); // Display a custom error notice
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (active theme). Tested and works.

---

Related: [Disable shopping when an item from a specific product category is in cart in Woocommerce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51938763/disable-shopping-when-an-item-from-a-specific-product-category-is-in-cart-in-woo/51941925#51941925)

Comment: could you please help me how to use the same code but with category term? For example, you have product attribute color and terms are: red, black, white. I do not know how to access "red" term and use it in your example instead of category slug 'beerservice'. Thank you very much for your help.