# Disable checkout based on an allowed time range in Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, datetime, woocommerce, cart

I need a time related checkout option (so if people order from past **`23.59`** to **`06.00`**, the checkout will be canceled and they will be redirected to an other page). I know how to build the logics but dont know the code for the time relation.

This time related checkout only needs to happen when a certain category is in the cart.

This is my code for now:

```
foreach( WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item ){

    if( is_checkout() && has_parent_term( $cart_item['product_id']) && TIME_IS > (SATURDAY 23:59) && TIME_IS < (SUNDAY 06:00)) {
      wp_redirect( get_permalink( get_option('woocommerce_cart_page_id') ) );
      wc_add_notice( sprintf( 'unfortunatly you are not able to puchase these items at this time'), 'error');
      exit;
    }
}
```

The conditional function `has_parent_term()` is defined in [this answer thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52601311/3730754).

Comment: updated hope you understand it :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following code will check for a defined product category in cart items **and a time range**. If the defined product category is found and **if time it's out of the defined time range** *(from **`06:00`** to **`23:59`**)*, a custom notice will be displed avoiding checkout.

> There is no need of redirection to cart when using `woocommerce_check_cart_items`  dedicated hook.

**For the time range conditional function:** 
- The formatted start and end time strings need to be like `hh:mm:ss` 
- You will have to define the time zone (see the [List of Supported Timezones](http://php.net/manual/en/timezones.php)

```
// Custom conditional function that checks for parent product categories from a product category slug
function has_parent_term( $product_id, $category_slug ) {

    // Convert category term slug to term id
    $category_id   = get_term_by('slug', $category_slug, 'product_cat')->term_id;
    $parent_term_ids = array(); // Initializing

    // Loop through the current product category terms to get only parent main category term
    foreach( get_the_terms( $product_id, 'product_cat' ) as $term ){
        if( $term->parent > 0 ){
            $parent_term_ids[] = $term->parent; // Set the parent product category
            $parent_term_ids[] = $term->term_id; // (and the child)
        } else {
            $parent_term_ids[] = $term->term_id;
        }
    }
    return in_array( $category_id, array_unique($parent_term_ids) );
}

// Custom conditional function that checks from a time range
function is_on_time( $start_time, $end_time, $time_zone = 'UTC' ) {
    // Set the default time zone (http://php.net/manual/en/timezones.php)
    date_default_timezone_set($time_zone);

    $from   = explode( ':', $start_time ); //
    $from_h = isset($from[0]) ? $from[0] : 0; // hours
    $from_m = isset($from[1]) ? $from[1] : 0; // minutes
    $from_s = isset($from[2]) ? $from[2] : 0; // seconds
    $start  = mktime( $from_h,  $from_m, $from_s, date("m"), date("d"), date("Y"));

    $to   = explode( ':', $end_time );
    $to_h = isset($to[0]) ? $to[0] : 0; // hours
    $to_m = isset($to[1]) ? $to[1] : 0; // minutes
    $to_s = isset($to[2]) ? $to[2] : 0; // seconds
    $end  = mktime( $to_h,  $to_m,  $to_s, date("m"), date("d"), date("Y"));

    $now   = strtotime("now");

    return ( $start >= $now && $end < $now ) ? true : false;
}

// Checking cart items and avoid checkout displaying an error notice
add_action( 'woocommerce_check_cart_items', 'woocommerce_check_cart_quantities' );
function woocommerce_check_cart_quantities() {
    $found = false; // Initializing

    // Loop through cart items
    foreach ( WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item ) {
        // Check for product category term and parent term
        if ( has_parent_term( $cart_item['product_id'], 't-shirts' ) )
            $found = true; // category is found
    }

    // Checking product category and time
    if ( $found && ! is_on_time( '6:00', '23:59', 'Europe/Paris' ) ){
        // Avoiding checkout displaying a custom error notice
        wc_add_notice( __("Sorry too late, time is now off. You are not allowed to checkout", "woocommerce" ), 'error' );
    }
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (active theme). Tested and works.

---

When time is over if any cart item remaining to a specific product category:

**1) In cart page:**

[image]

**2) In Checkout page:**

[image]

---

**Addition - Targeting days of the week** in the `is_on_time()` conditional function.

Replace `return ( $start >= $now && $end < $now ) ? true : false;` by one of the following, if you want to:

**1) Targeting 'Sundays'** only (example):

```
return ( $start >= $now && $end < $now && date('w') == '0' ) ? true : false;
```

**2) Targeting week end days** only (example):

```
return ( $start >= $now && $end < $now && in_array( date('w'), array('6','0') ) ) ? true : false;
```

**2) Targeting the working days** only (example):

```
return ( $start >= $now && $end < $now && ! in_array( date('w'), array('6','0') ) ) ? true : false;
```

Comment: @RMCS Think about it please: **For testing only** you will set the time zone to your own time zone : [List of Supported Timezones](http://php.net/manual/en/timezones.php) … For fridays and saturdays use `array( '5', '6')` … Last thing, can you clean all last comments please. Thanks.